# < > changed to &lt; and &gt; while parsing html with beautifulsoup in python

Tags: python, html, parsing, beautifulsoup

While processing html using Beautifulsoup, the < and > were converted to `&lt;`and `&gt;`, since the tag anchor were all converted, the whole soup lost its structure, any suggestion?

Answer (score 6):

Setting `formatter=None` may help (http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters), but this might be an indication that your HTML is invalid.

If that doesn't work, can you provide some sample code and HTML which reproduces the problem?

Comment: It might be an indication that you're using an XML/HTML library on a JSP file

Answer (score 0):

It can be due to an invalid character (due to charset encoding/decoding), therefor BeautifulSoup has issues to parse the input.
I solve it by passing my string directly to BeautifulSoup without doing any encoding/decoding.
In my case, I was trying to convert UTF-16 to UTF-8 myself.