# How do I set a BeautifulSoup attribute while preserving HTML entities?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

Setup:

```py
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup('<img/>', 'html.parser')
```

I need to do the following:

```py
soup.img['src'] = 'url?x=1&y=2'
```

Desired behavior:

```py
print(soup)
<img src="url?x=1&y=2"/>
```

Actual behavior:

```py
print(soup)
<img src="url?x=1&amp;y=2"/>
```

In general, how do I set a `Tag` attribute to the literal string I'm passing in?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [< > changed to &lt; and &gt; while parsing html with beautifulsoup in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14669283/changed-to-lt-and-gt-while-parsing-html-with-beautifulsoup-in-python)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `src` attribute is indeed stored as `'url?x=1&y=2'` however, when you do `print(soup)` BeautifulSoup applies formatting/escaping to avoid creating possibly incorrect HTML. If you want it to not do that, then you can explicitly declare it, eg:

```
print(soup.decode(formatter=None))
```

Reference: [Output formatters](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#output-formatters)

Answer (score 0):

The `&amp;` is just an `&`; try doing something like this:

```
soup.img['src'].replace('&amp;','&')
```

Output:

> 'url?x=1&y=2'